# Set transparent dots in probability plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy, statistics

I'm trying to set an `alpha` value or some other way of making dots in a probability plot slightly translucent. This is the code I have.

```
import numpy as np 
import pylab 
import scipy.stats as stats
stats.probplot(x, dist=stats.gamma, sparams=(2.74,),plot=pylab)
```

This is what the plot sort of looks like. Any tips on how to make the dots slightly translucent? I'd like to do this for aesthetic purposes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `probplot` function doesn't expose an API to customize the plot. Instead, you can customize the plot after `probplot` returns, using additional `matplotlib` (i.e. `pylab`) functions.  Here's one way you could do it (in an ipython session).

First, the imports:

```
In [102]: import numpy as np

In [103]: import pylab

In [104]: from scipy import stats
```

Generate some data for the plot:

```
In [105]: np.random.seed(8675309)

In [106]: x = np.random.gamma(3.0, scale=2.1, size=50)
```

Generate the probability plot:

```
In [107]: pp = stats.probplot(x, dist=stats.gamma, sparams=(2.74,), plot=pylab)
```

Set the `alpha` value for the first line in the current axes.  This is slightly "dangerous", because it relies on `probplot` plotting the points before plotting the red line.

```
In [108]: ax = pylab.gca()           # Get the current axes.

In [109]: line0 = ax.get_lines()[0]  # Get the first "line" in the axes.

In [110]: line0.set_alpha(0.25)      # Set the alpha for the "line".
```

Here's the plot that is generated:

[image: plot]

---

Personally, though, I prefer to take complete control of the plotting.  You can pass `None` for the `plot` argument to disable the automatic generation of a plot, and generate the plot however you like using `matplotlib`:

```
In [185]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [186]: (osm, osr), (slope, intercept, r) = stats.probplot(x, dist=stats.gamma, sparams=(2.74,), plot=None)

In [187]: plt.plot(osm, osr, 'o', alpha=0.5)
Out[187]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11469a6d8>]

In [188]: plt.plot(osm, slope*osm + intercept, 'k', alpha=0.5, linewidth=1)
Out[188]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x114695a90>]

In [189]: plt.grid(alpha=0.15)

In [190]: plt.xlabel('Theoretical Quantiles')
Out[190]: <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x11440bac8>

In [191]: plt.ylabel('Sample Quantiles')
Out[191]: <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x1142efda0>
```

[image: plot]

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you.